# EM algorithm for clustering of Gaussian Mixture models

Tags: cluster-analysis, pattern-recognition, expectation-maximization, gaussian-mixture-model

I have a multivariate dataset(4 dimensions) of 150 points. I should use EM algorithm to group the given set of points into clusters. The number of clusters to which these points fall into is also given as 3. So, the task is to find out the Gaussians of the three clusters.

I have used the EM algorithm for clustering of gaussian mixtures given in the book "Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006".[The algorithm is attached in the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ffze.png)

The code that I have written is as follows.

```
import numpy as np, math, pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
from decimal import Decimal


def clustering(points):
    points = list(set(points)) #To eliminate redundant points

    '''
    Initialize random gaussians!
    '''
    mean = [np.array([5,4,1.5,0.4]), np.array([4.5,5,0.5,0.5]), np.array([6,3,2,1])]
    covariance1 = np.array([[16,0,0,0], [0,4,0,0], [0,0,9,0], [0,0,0,1]])
    covariance2 = np.array([[4,0,0,0], [0,16,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,9]])
    covariance3 = np.array([[16,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,0,9,0], [0,0,0,4]])
    covariance = [covariance1, covariance2, covariance3]
    weights = np.array([0.3, 0.3, 0.4])

    init_log_likelihood = None #Log likelihood to test convergence, initially None
    threshold = 0.0000000000000000000001 #Threshold difference for convergence

    iterations = 0 #for counting iterations

    while True:
        iterations +=1 

        prob_dict = {point:[] for point in points}
        new_means = [np.array([0,0,0,0]) for _ in range(3)]
        new_covariance = [np.array([[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]) for _ in range(3)]

        log_likelihood = Decimal(0) #Using decimal to increase the precision of floating point numbers

        for point in points:

            prob_sum = 0 #Prob sum for normalization

            for _ in range(3):
                prob =  multivariate_normal.pdf(point, mean[_], covariance[_], allow_singular=True) #Finding gaussian probability
                prob = np.dot(weights[_], prob)+1 #Multiply gaussian probability with weight
                prob_dict[point].append(prob)
                prob_sum += prob
            
            prob_sum = Decimal(prob_sum)

            log_likelihood += prob_sum.ln() #comprehensive computation of log likelihood

            for _ in range(3):
                prob_dict[point][_] = prob_dict[point][_]/float(prob_sum) #Normalizing the probability
                new_means[_] = new_means[_]+np.dot(prob_dict[point][_], list(point)) #New means for the next iteration

        for _ in range(3):
            weights[_] = sum([prob_item[1][_] for prob_item in prob_dict.items()]) #New weights
            new_means[_] = np.divide(new_means[_], weights[_])
            for point in points:
              #New covariance
              new_covariance[_] = new_covariance[_]+np.dot(np.dot(prob_dict[point][_], (np.array(point)-new_means[_])),  np.transpose(np.array(point)-new_means[_]))
        
        for _ in range(3):
            new_covariance[_] = np.divide(new_covariance[_],weights[_])
            weights[_] = weights[_]/len(points)        
        
        mean = new_means 
        covariance = new_covariance

        #check for convergence
        if init_log_likelihood and abs(init_log_likelihood-log_likelihood)<=threshold:
            break

        init_log_likelihood = log_likelihood

    print("Means: ", mean)
    print("Covariance: ", covariance)
    print("Log-likehilhood: ", log_likelihood)
    print("Iterations: ", iterations)
```

After certain number of iterations I always observe that the three gaussians converge into one i.e.; the parameters (mean, covariance matrix) for all the gaussians are same. But I should get three different gaussians as the given set of points fall into three clusters.

Please help me to figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: WAS THIS QUESTION ANSWERED?

Comment: @onyambu No, it was not. But over the time, I figured out that I am calculating the covariance matrix using the direct formula. This was the problem. If I used a library function like `np.cov` to calculate the covarince, then everything falls to its own place. If you are interested, you can take a look at the updated code [here](https://github.com/sasivs/expectation-maximization/blob/main/em.py)

Comment: @onyambu Further, I have used aweights in the covarince function call whose significance is mentioned [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html)